# Write a custom query in Crystal Report by visual studio c#

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I want to create a Crystal report that takes values from 3 MySQL tables but I want to write my custom query because when I select tables in visual studio it shows a query that doesn't meet what I expected.
I tested query on localhost phpMyAdmin and it worked.

note 1: I am using visual studio 2019 and installed Crystal report SP26
note 2: when visual studio wrote the query it added "1" to the table name
like boq_table make it boq_table1.

code below represents what query I want to execute:

```
SELECT
    ubc.boq_table.itemNum,
    ubc.boq_table.descriptionOfWork,
    ubc.boq_table.unit,
    ubc.boq_table.contractualQuantity,
    ubc.boq_table.priceNum,
    ubc.summary.executedQuantLastSummary,
    ubc.summary.priceLastWorks,
    ubc.summary.executedQuantBetw2Sum,
    ubc.submittal.priceCurrentWorks
FROM
    ubc.boq_table
LEFT OUTER JOIN ubc.summary ON
    ubc.boq_table.itemNum = ubc.summary.itemNum
LEFT OUTER JOIN ubc.submittal ON
    ubc.boq_table.itemNum = ubc.submittal.itemNum
WHERE
    ubc.boq_table.projectName ='proj'
UNION
SELECT
    ubc.boq_table.itemNum,
    ubc.boq_table.descriptionOfWork, 
    ubc.boq_table.unit, 
    ubc.boq_table.contractualQuantity, 
    ubc.boq_table.priceNum, 
    ubc.summary.executedQuantLastSummary, 
    ubc.summary.priceLastWorks, 
    ubc.summary.executedQuantBetw2Sum, 
    ubc.submittal.priceCurrentWorks 
FROM
    ubc.summary
LEFT OUTER JOIN ubc.boq_table ON 
    ubc.summary.itemNum = ubc.boq_table.itemNum 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ubc.submittal ON 
    ubc.summary.itemNum = ubc.submittal.itemNum 
WHERE 
    ubc.summary.projectName = 'proj'  
UNION
SELECT
    ubc.boq_table.itemNum,
    ubc.boq_table.descriptionOfWork,
    ubc.boq_table.unit,
    ubc.boq_table.contractualQuantity,
    ubc.boq_table.priceNum,
    ubc.summary.executedQuantLastSummary, 
    ubc.summary.priceLastWorks, 
    ubc.summary.executedQuantBetw2Sum, 
    ubc.submittal.priceCurrentWorks 
FROM
    ubc.submittal 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ubc.boq_table ON 
    ubc.submittal.itemNum = ubc.boq_table.itemNum 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ubc.summary ON 
    ubc.submittal.itemNum = ubc.summary.itemNum 
WHERE 
    ubc.submittal.projectName = 'proj' 
ORDER BY 
    itemNum;
```

and this code was written by the visual studio after I selected tables

```
 SELECT boq_table1.itemNum, boq_table1.descriptionOfWork, boq_table1.unit, boq_table1.contractualQuantity, boq_table1.priceNum, submittal1.priceCurrentWorks, summary1.executedQuantLastSummary, summary1.executedQuantBetw2Sum, summary1.priceLastWorks
 FROM   (ubc.boq_table boq_table1 INNER JOIN ubc.submittal submittal1 ON boq_table1.ID=submittal1.ID) INNER JOIN ubc.summary summary1 ON boq_table1.ID=summary1.ID
 ORDER BY boq_table1.itemNum
```

the last code read-only I can't edit

Comment: use the msq connector https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/8.0.html to create datasets with your data and use that as data source for crystal report

Comment: I already downloaded and created a connection with my database to connect from Crystal report and fill report with data

Comment: You can do 2 things, you look again in the database selector, there is an option for adding a command or use the connector and a datareader to build a dataset that you can use.

Comment: thank you, it worked and accept query in command but I still have a problem because of crystal report contain null values (actually it is nothing values or not found) and the following error appears "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" anyway, please write your last comment below to mark as accepted and I will ask my new question in individual post.

Comment: Run your query in mysql workbench and see, if you get data at all. The sql command interpreter of Crystal reports may also have problems with some querys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do 2 things if you want to get data to crystal reprots, you look again in the database selector, there is an option for adding a command or use the connector and a datareader to build a dataset that you can use.

The first is ok, if you don't need to compute the data heavily.