# Crystal Report does not show data when 1 of the 2 datatables in dataset return empty rows

Tags: mysql, vb.net, crystal-reports

I'm trying to show data from two Datatables by crystal report but I faced a problem that when there is data in two tables the report is working very well but if there is no data in any one table the data in another Datatable not showing!
I'm using the next code to populate the data and load the report:

```
Public Class FR_Parents_Rep2

Dim xCLS As New ClsMain
Dim xDadp As MySqlDataAdapter
Dim xDS As Ds_Edsa


Private Sub btnView_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnView.Click
    Try
        If xCLS.MyCodes_CboNotNull_Index(Me.CboParents, "TheParent") = True Then Exit Sub

        Dim xParentID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Me.CboParents.SelectedValue)
        Dim xFatoraID, xFrom, xTo As TextObject
        Dim xreport As New Rpt_Parents_Rep2

        xFatoraID = CType(xreport.ReportDefinition.Sections("Section1").ReportObjects("TxtDate"), TextObject)
        xFrom = CType(xreport.ReportDefinition.Sections("Section1").ReportObjects("TxtFrom"), TextObject)
        xTo = CType(xreport.ReportDefinition.Sections("Section1").ReportObjects("TxtTo"), TextObject)

        xDS = New Ds_Edsa

        Dim xSql2 As String
        xSql2 = "SELECT 
            Sum(tbl_parents_payments.TheAmount) AS PrevMadf 
            FROM tbl_parents_payments
            WHERE (((tbl_parents_payments.ParentID)=@ParentID) 
            AND ((tbl_parents_payments.TheDate)<@Date1));"

        Dim xCMD2 As New MySqlCommand(xSql2, Conn)
        xCMD2.Parameters.Add("@Date1", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = CDate(Me.TxtFrom.Value)
        xCMD2.Parameters.Add("@ParentID", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = xParentID
        xDadp = New MySqlDataAdapter(xCMD2)
        xDadp.Fill(xDS.Tables("PrevData2"))

        '..............................................................................................

        Dim xSql3 As String
        xSql3 = "SELECT tbl_parents_payments.TheDate, 
                        tbl_parents_payments.TheAmount
                        FROM tbl_parents_payments
                WHERE (((tbl_parents_payments.TheDate) 
                Between @Date1 And @Date2) AND 
                ((tbl_parents_payments.ParentID)=@ParentID));"
        Dim xCMD3 As New MySqlCommand(xSql3, Conn)
        xCMD3.Parameters.Add("@Date1", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = CDate(Me.TxtFrom.Value)
        xCMD3.Parameters.Add("@Date2", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = CDate(Me.TxtTo.Value)
        xCMD3.Parameters.Add("@ParentID", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = xParentID
        xDadp = New MySqlDataAdapter(xCMD3)
        xDadp.Fill(xDS.Tables("ParPay"))
        '..............................................................................................


        xFatoraID.Text = Now.ToString("mmhhAyyyyMMdd")


        xFrom.Text = CStr(Me.TxtFrom.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"))


        xTo.Text = CStr(Me.TxtTo.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"))

        '..............................................................................................
        xreport.SetDataSource(xDS)
        Crpt.ReportSource = Nothing
        Crpt.ReportSource = xreport
        Crpt.Refresh()
        xDadp.Dispose()
        xDS.Dispose()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(Me_MsgErrorStr + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + ex.Message, Me_MsgInfoStyle, Me_MsgCaptionStr)
    Finally
        Conn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

the next image tells how the Dataset is appearing.
[image]

thanks, advanced

Comment: that is not how crystal Reports work, 1. You  make da datasource and then vreate a Report and then add elements to it see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60015411/write-a-custom-query-in-crystal-report-by-visual-studio-c-sharp/60016086#60016086

Comment: @nbk your solution not working for me, what I need is get the payments between two dates and the specified parent (ParPay Datatable), and get the previous payments for the same parent, the problem is if there are no payments between the two dates it will not show the previous payments even there are payments

Comment: look my solution works, as long you get the data into a dataset and use that as basis for your report(rpt). The only thing that doesn't work is your approach. Besides show us the table not the result, maybe you could  join them, but as dataset and two tables os ok for crystal report. or any other reporting tool.. Look also in the links in  posted in the commend

Comment: @nbk I don't want to link the Datatables , I think that I created this problem because it happened due something wrong that I don't know it and maybe because of my approach! so if you can help me please do it, and if not I will thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I think that nobody will try to help us here regarding MySql and Crystal report else @nbk and Mr. nbk is not ready to deal with beginners as I saw that through this post and a previous post.
anyway, I found the solution at the next link:
[The Solution](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/20968933/Crystal-Report-does-not-show-data-when-1-of-the-2-datatables-in-dataset-return-empty-rows.html)

**good luck**